# In tensorflow, how to separate by sentences when running word2vec model?

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec

In gensim word2vec, the input can be a list of sentences. However, in tensorflow word2vec, the input is a list of words (concatenate sentences together). Is there a way to separate the sentences when constructing {target word, context word} pairs? 
I am using the following code:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.8/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py

Comment: What do you mean  {target word, context word}? I think you just need words from sentences, and the skim-gram model figures out the context words.

Comment: @SungKim yes, skim-gram model will figure out the context words. But it seems that the current model only supports for a long list of words, and it constructs {target word, context word} pairs within each minibatch. I would like to construct {target word, context word} pairs within each sentence instead.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you do not want words at the end of a sentence to be associated (be part of the same local context window) with the words at the beginning of the next sentence. If so, there are a few different ways to achieve this.

It you do not want to make any code modifications on the word2vec example code, the simplest way is to add a few spacer words at the end and beginning of each sentence. You will need to add as many words as your `window_size` parameter. The default `window_size` is `5`.

If an example sentence is:
`The dog jumped over the fence`
You will need to add spacers (`XYZ` here) to the beginning and end as:
`XYZ XYZ XYZ XYZ XYZ The dog jumped over the fence XYZ XYZ XYZ XYZ XYZ`

Answer (score 0):

That example uses a custom op for data processing mostly to get the best possible performance. You can just feed data yourself instead and get the pairs of words to train on however you wish, it just might be a bit slower with small minibatches. With large minibatches it shouldn't be too slow, but for these types of models you might get the best learning progress with smaller minibatches.

Comment: Can you advise on how to do that? I figured I need to change the following step:   `(words, counts, words_per_epoch, self._epoch, self._words, examples,
     labels) = word2vec.skipgram(filename=opts.train_data,
                                 batch_size=opts.batch_size,
                                 window_size=opts.window_size,
                                 min_count=opts.min_count,
                                 subsample=opts.subsample)` So I need to write my own skip-gram algorithm? Besides, the output from above skipgram are tensors. not sure how to construct tensors myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Skip-gram pair generator from Tensorflow example: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.9/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py

```
# Step 3: Function to generate a training batch for the skip-gram model.
def generate_batch(batch_size, num_skips, skip_window):
  global data_index
  assert batch_size % num_skips == 0
  assert num_skips <= 2 * skip_window
  batch = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size), dtype=np.int32)
  labels = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, 1), dtype=np.int32)
  span = 2 * skip_window + 1 # [ skip_window target skip_window ]
  buffer = collections.deque(maxlen=span)
  for _ in range(span):
    buffer.append(data[data_index])
    data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(data)
  for i in range(batch_size // num_skips):
    target = skip_window  # target label at the center of the buffer
    targets_to_avoid = [ skip_window ]
    for j in range(num_skips):
      while target in targets_to_avoid:
        target = random.randint(0, span - 1)
      targets_to_avoid.append(target)
      batch[i * num_skips + j] = buffer[skip_window]
      labels[i * num_skips + j, 0] = buffer[target]
    buffer.append(data[data_index])
    data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(data)
  return batch, labels
```

If you run above module, you will get {target word, context word} pairs within each mini-batch.

For example, if your data looks like

```
data: ['anarchism', 'originated', 'as', 'a', 'term', 'of', 'abuse']
```

Then you will get input and output pair below:

```
with num_skips = 2 and skip_window = 1:
    batch: ['originated', 'originated', 'as', 'as', 'a', 'a', 'term', 'term', 'of', 'of', 'abuse', 'abuse', 'first', 'first', 'used', 'used']
    labels: ['as', 'anarchism', 'originated', 'a', 'term', 'as', 'a', 'of', 'term', 'abuse', 'of', 'first', 'used', 'abuse', 'against', 'first']
```

Because the skip gram predicts context words: `originated -> as`, `originated -> anarchism`.

I have CBOW batch generator implementation as well. Comment it if you want me to post that here as well.